# how to use the result of the data from firebase to post in the array

Tags: reactjs, firebase

This is my first time using Firestore. I am not able to get the data from firestore when I add filter by date and when put in table get me this :
console.log(state) affiche :

[image]

console.log(state[0]) affiche :

[image]

how to use the result of the state to post in the array

```
export default function TableList() {
  const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth()
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setstate] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    var users = [];
    db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push(data);
        });
      });
    setstate(users);
  }, []);
console.log(state[0])
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>    
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Card plain>
          <CardBody>
            <Table
              tableHeaderColor="primary"
              tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Country", "City", "Salary"]}
              tableData={[["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger", "Oud-Turnhout"],["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao", "Sinaai-Waas"]]}
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `then` make sure to change the stat inside of it. Othervise you will change the state with an empty array.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    
    db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        //Cange        
        var users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push(data);
        });
        //Change
        setstate(users);
      });
    
  }, []);
```

The code is asynchronous so when you use `then` the code in `then` will happen somewhere in the future but the rest of your code is executed immidiately so your `setstate` was executed before `then`. Because of that your state was empty. By puting the `setstate` inside of the `then` it will change the state when there is actualy data.